# Iterable lazy functions getting too lazy

Tags: dart

This code trips me up. In this code the *takeWhile* makes sense - take up debits, reducing the balance while the balance is positive. The problem is with this code nothing happens. No calls to *balance.debit()* are made and I guess the reason is *takeWhile filtering happens lazily*.

I can ensure that it gets called by tacking on a *toList()* call, but that seems wasteful as a list is not really needed.

- What is a better way to do this?
- Is *takeWhile* not the right tool for this job?

Code follows:

```dart
class Balance {
  Balance(this._balance);
  double _balance;
  debit(double amount) {
    print('Debiting $amount');
    return (_balance -= amount);
  }
}

main() {
  final balance = new Balance(3.0);
  final debits = [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ];
  debits.takeWhile((debit) => balance.debit(debit) > 0);

  //////////////////////
  //debits
  //  .takeWhile((debit) => balance.debit(debit) > 0)
  //  .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `takeWhile` is not the right tool for this job.

As you noticed, it is lazy. It is intended to create a new iterable, and it only does something if you actually use that iterable. Here, you are not interested in the result at all, so you just want the "while" part, and don't care about the "take". Alternative:

```dart
for (debit in debits) {
  if (balance.debit(debit) < 0) break;
}
```

I even find it easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is described in the api doc of [Iterable.takeWhile](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.Iterable#id_takeWhile) :

> The filtering happens lazily.

To enforce evaluation you can use `.length`, `.forEach((_){})`, `.toList()` (...) on the result of `takeWhile(...)`

Comment: Is this something the Dart Analyzer could be trained to flag (e.g. 'Warning: code that does nothing')? Which of these alternatives is the least hit to performance? What about a new method on Iterable called (.iterate() or .noop() or .doIt()) so the user can force it with out having to count items, call a noop on each, or create a list?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this is because it is lazy evaluated. You need something that enforces iterating over the result. If you don't want to create a list you could also do something like:

```dart
var r = debits.takeWhile((debit) => balance.debit(debit) > 0);
for(var x in r) {
  // print(x);
}
```